# MySQL join two table matching with their id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this two table:

**Table One: user**

```
id   name   home_location    job_location
1    Jack   40               5
2    Rocky  50               4  
3    Tom    24               9
```

**Table Two: area**

```
area_id    area_name
5          Bukit Batok
4          Bukit Panjang
9          Boon Lay
40         Pioneer
50         Choa Chu Kang
24         Clementi
```

I want result like this:

```
ID    name    home_location   job_location
1     Jack    Pioneer         Bukit Batok
2     Rocky   Choa Chu Kang   Bukit Panjang
3     Tom     Clementi        Boon Lay
```

As i am not good in sql query so how to write select query.
Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like

```
SELECT id as ID,
             name,
             area_1.area_name as home_location,
             area_2.area_name as job_location,
             area_1.area_id as home_location_id,
             area_2.area_id as job_location_id   
FROM user 
INNER JOIN 
      area AS area_1 
           ON area_1.area_id = user.home_location
INNER JOIN 
      area AS area_2
           ON area_2.area_id = user.job_location
```

And try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Comment: Sorry @Adsy2010 I forgotted `INNER`

Comment: I didnt see even that is missing.Thanks once again @Adsy2010.

Comment: @Adsy2010 In mysql unqualified join is inner join.

Comment: @takwlasnie `unqualified` means..??

Comment: Hi Thanks for your code but i am getting  Unknown column 'area_2.area_name' in 'field list'. Can you please help me :)

Comment: @Gautam3164 if you write just JOIN it is the same as INNER JOIN. It's like INNER JOIN is the default join in mysql if it's not sppecified. So it's fine to write just JOIN.

Comment: Learn something new every day

Comment: @Adsy2010 it is for me..??

Comment: Hi your query is runing but in home_location i am getting 40,50,24. I need this: Pioneer, Choa Chu Kang, Clementi

Comment: @Gautam3164 You query is perfect. Need your small help i want also home_location and job_location as number. Can you help me plz :)

Comment: Simply add `area_1.area_id as home_location_id,
                 area_2.area_id as job_location_id` as like in my ans now

Comment: @Gautam3164 Thank you for everything Gautam :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select U.ID,U.Name,A1.Area_Name as Home_Location, A2.Area_name as Job_Location
From Users U
Left Outer Join Area A1 ON U.home_location = A1.Area_ID
Left Outer Join Area A2 ON U.job_location = A2.Area_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is this:

```
select
    us.name,
    us.home_location,
    ar.job_location
from
    user us
        join area ar
            on us.area_id=ar.id
```

but please, take a read of this [Q&A I wrote for justthis situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables).